# Many UIViews + QLViewController = very slow performance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I am building a calendar control. It generally works well and is responsive, despite using **hundreds** of UIViews (each cell in the example image is a UIView).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g1hQ.png

I have run into a problem in which the calendar is put in an app. It is fully obscured by some other controls and finally by a Quick Look viewcontroller. **When the Quick Look is dismissed** it takes a long time (10 seconds) before the app appears to respond.

- Any view other than Quick Look has no slowness symptoms

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: mind sharing some code ?

Comment: Are you using a UICollectionView or some kind of cell-reusing architecture to keep your memory footprint low when scrolling this monster?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I guess SOF isn't sending me notifications.

Comment: I don't think I can show you any code that would be useful. The calendar is created with a fairly complex abstraction layer that makes the UI platform-agnostic.

The calendar is not using a cell-reusing architecture, because about 50% of the cells are visible at any given time. I **have** tried limiting the number of control to only those that are visible, and while it does make the delay somewhat shorter, it is not a solution; that is, it may be done later as an optimization, but isn't a major contributor to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Autolayout. It simply cannot handle more than a trial number of views. Each nested view impacts the rendering time exponentially.

I end up writing my own "MagicLayout" system that does the same job, but it takes about 500 ms instead of 10000ms. The amount of time to dismiss a ViewController went from 10 seconds to about 10ms

Coming soon to a Xamarin component store near you.